# R date conversion

Tags: r, format, posixct, date-conversion

I have a date in format `"%e-%a-%y"` example: `"13-Mar-15"`

I need to convert this date in format `"%Y-%m-%d"`

I have tried format(example, `"%Y-%m-%d"`) without success.
Also tried

```
format(as.POSIXct(example, format="%e-%a-%y"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

without success.

Edit: I know what happened I had the wrong format:"%e-%a-%y".
It needed to be "%d-%b-%y"
It was late and when I wrote my initial format, so I wasn't thinking very clearly: "%a" was for the abbreviated day. 
The error was that I was trying to convert without the proper source format. "%b" is the abbreviated month, which should work for this question.

Comment: Posting answers, is not the only way to help. Editing a badly formatted question is important too. Especially for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had the wrong format :

```
as.Date("13-Mar-15", "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2015-03-13"
```

For the formats, `%d` is the day, `%b` is the abbreviated month and `%y` the year (two-digits)

`%a` is an abbreviated weekday name. You could also use

```
as.Date("13-Mar-15", "%e-%b-%y")
[1] "2015-03-13"
```

as `%e` is also the day (format 1-31) where `%d` is 01-31. read `?strptime` for more info on the date format.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `lubridate`, where it is easy to convert to `POSIXct` class.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(v1)
#[1] "2015-03-13 UTC"
```

#### data

```
v1 <-  "13-Mar-15"
```